# gridview.Datasource and gridview.Datamember which I should set first?

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress, datasource, datamember

If I want to set both gridview.datasource and gridview.datamember, which one I should set first? Is there any standard order about this? Thank you!

Comment: Usually I set the datamember first.  That way, when you set the datasource, it will refresh the grid using the datamember info.  (If the datasource is a dataset, the datamember would be a table.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer to set `gridview.datasource` first and then only `gridview.datamember` because you do not need to set `gridview.datamember` property when binding to a data source that contains a single list or table.

Answer (score 0):

Usually I set the datamember first. That way, when you set the datasource, it will refresh the grid using the datamember info. (If the datasource is a dataset, the datamember would be a table.  If you set the datasource first and then the datamember, the datagrid will stay empty until explicitly refreshed.)

I do the same with all databound controls.  For listboxes, I set the displaymember and valuemember first and then the datasource.  The listbox then automatically has the proper info displayed.